# How to get system hardware info in c# without using System.Management class?

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I've looked it all on google and different forms but everyone is giving a solution using wmi query.

System Ids required:-
1. cpuID = Processor unique id or Processor id or Processor name
2. biosID = BIOS serial number
3. baseID = Motherboard base id
4. hddID = Harddisk serial number
5. macID = Mac Address

After getting these ids, I generate a hash which serves as a unique identifier. Now, I can easily get them using System.Management class but the problem is on some of the user machines wmic service is disabled somehow.

Even if I can get any one of the above mentioned ids, I can generate a unique hash. Does anyone know any method(Win api or something else) other than using System.Management class to achieve this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You don't mind to use P/Invoke to get this information? because you can find most of these [here](http://www.pinvoke.net). For example, to get hard disk drive serial number you can p/invoke [GetVolumeInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetVolumeInformation)

Comment: IDs 1-3 can only be queried direct from hardware. There are no Win32 APIs for them outside of WMI (but there are plenty of 3rd party implementations that can handle the required hardware calls for you). There are Win32 APIs that can retrieve IDs 4-5 (`GetVolumeInformation` for 4, `GetAdaptersInfo`/`GetAdaptersAddresses` for 5)